# perl command line subsitution

Tags: regex, perl, command-line, substitution

I have a list of ips or hostnames and i want to compare  them to my database, i'm trying to do it via commandline and i'll break it down.

my ip list looks like this

```
10.0.0.1
10.1.1.1
10.2.2.2
hostname-as-12
... etc
```

my database is like this:

```
hostname:ip:location:contact
```

pseudo code is like

```
open iplist
compare to database
replace inline iplist with new information
```

i want to do this from the command line(if nothing then to learn more about using it)

currently my command line looks like this:

```
perl -i.back -pe 's/^(.+)$/$1:`grep $1 /directory/tmp/datbase.txt` | cut -d : -f2`/' iplist
```

so then iplist will be changed like this

```
10.0.0.1:10.0.0.1
10.1.1.1:10.1.1.1
10.2.2.2:           #case not found
hostname-as-12:10.3.3.3
```

Comment: You don't need to use regex nor perl, you can do this with awk.

Comment: You don't need to use awk, you can do this with Perl.

Comment: Is your database file very large?

Comment: In that case: Read the database file into a hash, then use the hash to match the ips. It will be a lot faster and more accurate than your current solution.

Comment: I was trying to do this as a command line solution, would this be the most elegant way?

Comment: _not_ doing it as a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

In command-line Perl you can use a `BEGIN` block to create the hash first at the start. The `File::Slurp` module gives you a shortcut for reading the database file.

The additional `-l` option adds a newline after every print, so that you can safely `chomp` the input & use it as a hash key, without having to remember to include an extra newline in the output:

```
perl -i.back -MFile::Slurp -ple 'BEGIN { %db = map {m/^([^:]+):([^:]+)/; ($2 => $1)} read_file("/directory/tmp/database.txt") } chomp; $_ .= ":" . $db{$_} || ""' iplist
```

Test:

```
$ cat iplist
10.0.0.1
10.1.1.1
10.2.2.2
hostname-as-12
$ cat db.txt
10.0.0.1:10.0.0.1:foo:bar
10.1.1.1:10.1.1.1:foo:bar
10.3.3.3:hostname-as-12:foo:bar
$ perl -i.back -MFile::Slurp -ple 'BEGIN { %db = map {m/^([^:]+):([^:]+)/; ($2 => $1)} read_file("db.txt") } chomp; $_ .= ":" . $db{$_} || ""' iplist
$ cat iplist
10.0.0.1:10.0.0.1
10.1.1.1:10.1.1.1
10.2.2.2:
hostname-as-12:10.3.3.3
$
```

Without the `File::Slurp` module you would just need to open and read the file as you would normally, in that same `BEGIN` block, to fill the `%db` hash.